# Grammar for "noun is followed by a clause"

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

> This leads to difficulties when trying to control the ABI of a shared
> library: one must apply attributes to and export the whole class from
> the shared library, **which is not an option some members of the class
> should not be exported.**

Here how are "which is not an option" and "some members of the class should not be exported." connected? Is it grammatically correct?

Original source comes from https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1263r0.pdf

I think it should be "which is not an option when some members of the class should not be exported." Is it right?

Comment: Something is not right with that clause. Where did you find it?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Without knowing what the author had in mind, one can use one's imagination to correct it. But that's off-topic here anyway.

Comment: @fev So the above sentence is grammatically incorrect. right?

Comment: 'which is not an option X some members of the class should not be exported' X can be **when/where/if, as/because/since** (or a **colon** or **semicolon** or **dash**), depending on meaning, but not absent.

Comment: @Edwin Yes, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

After reading "which is not an option some members of the class...", I would expect a transitive verb.

```
which is not an option
             ^object^^

some members of the class
^^^^subject^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
should not (be exported)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^intransitive verb
```

However, changing "be exported" to "export" would make a double negative, so that sentence is probably missing the word "if" after the word "option", as the comments point out.

In that case, the sentence makes perfect sense:

> ... one must apply attributes to and export the whole class from the shared library, which is not an option [if] some members of the class should not be exported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; there is a missing word there, possibly *when* or *if*:

> This leads to difficulties when trying to control the ABI of a shared library: one must apply attributes to and export the whole class from the shared library, which is not an option **if** some members of the class should not be exported.

Otherwise the relative clause would have two main verbs ("is" and "should").